# Why would Vim be outputting these strings randomly?

Tags: vim

There is a line of text that gets randomly written into the window. It happens a) when I start Vim, and b) some other random times. At startup, I'm getting the "Press ENTER or type command to continue" prompt, which I think is being triggered by this "message".

#### a) When I start Vim

```
filetype=  scrolloff=0
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

#### b) Randomly

This text shows up in the window, and looks like it is part of the file, but it's not really there. If I scroll, it goes away (but sometimes stays annoying over other text).

#### What I've tried

1. `set shortmess=atI`

   Hard to say for sure, but I think this is being trigged by the weird `filetype=  scrolloff=0` thing that's there.
2. Check the registers (that text is not there)

**What should I check next?**

Comment: Your "randomly" description makes it sound like your terminal is not fully functional (Vim is trying to remove the message and failing).  Do you get warnings when using `less` etc.?

Comment: @Kevin: No, I don't get any problems when I run `less`. Other than this, things are working normal with my terminal. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this command to create a log:

```
 vim -V9vim.log
```

The [logs](http://pastebin.com/1WNwyXJX) didn't indicate any problems, but I found two lines creating this problem:

```
set scrolloff
set filetype
```

I changed that to:

```
set scrolloff=1
filetype plugin on
```